# How to recover a database that has been deleted by installing a theme plugin for UI?

Tags: sql, plsql, database-administration, recycle-bin, flashback

I am currently building a database in my class in SQL PLSQL.

Using Apex Oracle, I made a huge mistake,installed a new apex theme plugin and set it as my current theme to enhance the UI. This plugin replaced my database with all of its own stuff and my tables and data are nowhere to be found.

Is there a `FLASHBACK` command for databases? Anything at all? Thank you

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User

Comment: Yes. It is called backups. Contact your DBA and request to restore the database from your daily backups.

Answer (score 0):

You may give [Restoring Tables from the Recycle Bin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#i1011362) a try, but not very sure if it would work in your case.

May need `SYSDBA` access

```
SELECT object_name, original_name, createtime FROM recyclebin;
```

Alternatively you can use `DBA_recyclebin` or `USER_RECYCLEBIN`

Once you find the object(table) that was dropped. you can flashback it using below statement

```
FLASHBACK TABLE <Your dropped table> TO BEFORE DROP 
   RENAME TO <Your new table name>;
```

[Read more here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#i1011340)